# Assignment statement inside for-loop

Tags: c++, c, arrays, for-loop, printf

The following code is that I wrote to test my understanding of using `for-loop` in `C`, and using assignment statement inside `for-loop` in particular. But here I am getting unexpected output. Why does it do not assign `0` to the first 10 element of the `array` ?

And why does it do not print the `array` at all if I declare the array as `array[10]` instead of `array[11]`? 
Can anybody explain  ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i, array[11];  //array[10]
  for (i = 0; ((i < 10) || (array[i] = 0)); ++i);
  for (i = 0; ((i < 10) && (printf("%d\n", array[i]))); ++i);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both problems are in this line:

```
  int for (i = 0; ((i < 10) || (array[i] = 0)); ++i);
```

First the program needs to evaluate `((i < 10) || (array[i] = 0))`. During first 10 iterations condition `(i < 10)` is satisfied (not `0`), the program **doesn't need** to evaluate `array[i] = 0` to know that the whole expression is true, so it doesn't execute the second part at all and the assignment is not done.

After the first 10 iterations, when `i` becomes `10` and  `(i < 10)` is no longer true, the program finally assignes `0` to `array[i]` but it is `array[10]` - the **eleventh** element of `array`. When the array has only ten elements the assignment crashes the program.

Comment: but, why does the second `for-loop` doesn't even `printf' garbage values ?

Comment: It should print the garbage, at least when the array size is 11 (checked in VS2010). If the array size is 10, the program may crash on assignment which is before printing, especially when compiled in some debugging configuration (with array bound check).

Answer (score 6):

```
((i < 10) || (array[i] = 0))
```

The `||` is lazy, as long as `i < 10`, the expression will [short circuit](http://c-faq.com/expr/shortcircuit.html) and the assignment will not even be evaluated.

The obvious way to change the loop would be to to;

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
    array[i] = 0;
```

...which is more readable and does exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: And if you really don't want to use the body of the `for` loop (for whatever reason), you could use the comma operator in the third part of the `for`: `for(i = 0; i < 10; array[i] = 0, ++i);`

Answer (score 3):

When it checks `(i < 10) || (array[i] = 0)` it short-circuits. Since i is less than 10, it never does the asignment - the statement will be true while `i<10`.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (i = 0; ((i < 10) || (array[i] = 0)); ++i);
```

this loop checks the value of i whether it si less than 10 or not bt not equals to 10 so u will need to add aditional logical operatior over there,

```
for (i = 0; ((i <= 10) || (array[i] = 0)); ++i);
```

Answer (score 0):

To assign zeroes the easy way to go is to use:

```
int array[11] = {0};
```

In the loop, (i < 10) gets TRUE, so it doesn't continue to (array[i] = 0)

you can replace:

```
((i < 10) || (array[i] = 0))
```

with this

```
((i < 10) | (array[i] = 0))
```

it will force the evaluation of the right side, even if left is true.

But when variable i will get the value 10, it will continue and do arr[10] = 0...
So if you want your array to be of size 10, it might be an issue.

Comment: No, the assignment was fully intentional.

Comment: i was trying to fill the array with `0`. its not a conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of compiler optimization. When compiler evaluating ||(Logical OR), First it checks whether left side value is true or false. If left side value is true, It dont execute the right side value. In your code until i becomes 10 it don't evaluates the array[i] =0;

If you want to make it work for every value of i, you can reduce the optimization level of compiler.

Comment: it's not "compiler optimization" but the mandatory language rules